# zsh: parsing wildcards in variables used in arguments on zsh commands?

Tags: shell, variables, terminal, zsh, wildcard

`ls *.txt` shows all files whose name ends with `.txt`

However if I do the following on a zsh shell: (on macOS 10.15 Catalina in my case)

```
a=*.txt
b='*.txt'
c="*.txt"

# trying no quotes, single quotes, double quotes
# although doesn't make any difference here

ls $a
ls $b
ls $c
ls "$a"
ls "$b"
ls "$c"
```

I'm getting

> ls: *.txt: No such file or directory

in all cases. How do I include wildcards in a variable and then have commands like `ls` actually process it as wildcards, rather than literal characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `~`(tilde) between `$` and variable name
to perform globbing in zsh. That is

```
ls $~a
```

Comment: Note that the effect of this is to temporarily enable the `GLOB_SUBST` for this one parameter expansion; you can also set the option using `setopt GLOB_SUBST` to apply to all subsequent parameter expansions.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable wildcards in zsh by using the command:

`unsetopt nomatch`

If you want to make the change permanent, put the command above into your `.zshrc` file.